# Named.Service is not active

Tags: server, 20.04, services, bind

How do I fix `named.service is not active, cannot reload.`? 
The output for `/etc/init.d/named status` is

```
● named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-15 16:24:00 UTC; 2h 42min ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
    Process: 55460 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 55460 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: creating TCP socket: address in use
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: listening on IPv4 interface enp0s25, 192.168.0.5#53
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: creating TCP socket: address in use
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: unable to listen on any configured interfaces
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: loading configuration: failure
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz named[55460]: exiting (due to fatal error)
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz systemd[1]: named.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 15 16:24:00 sturtz systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 15 19:02:52 sturtz systemd[1]: named.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

I can't figure out the error or how to fix it. I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, I installed it yesterday, I have asked about Bind9 setup [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202539/i-need-help-with-setting-up-dns)
When I run `sudo ss -tulpn | grep :53`:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host sturtz: Name or service not known
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                 192.168.0.5:53                                           0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=30))                                              
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                 192.168.0.5:53                                           0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=31))                                              
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                   127.0.0.1:53                                           0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=24))                                              
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                   127.0.0.1:53                                           0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=25))                                              
udp     UNCONN   0        0                               127.0.0.53%lo:53                                           0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=826,fd=12))                                      
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                     0.0.0.0:5353                                         0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("mdns-publisher",pid=1229,fd=5))                                       
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                       [::1]:53                                              [::]:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=36))                                              
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                       [::1]:53                                              [::]:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=35))                                              
udp     UNCONN   0        0          [fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f]%enp0s25:53                                              [::]:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=40))                                              
udp     UNCONN   0        0          [fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f]%enp0s25:53                                              [::]:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=41))                                              
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                        [::]:5353                                            [::]:*                                   users:(("mdns-publisher",pid=1229,fd=6))                                       
tcp     LISTEN   0        10                                192.168.0.5:53                                           0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=34),("named",pid=34374,fd=33),("named",pid=34374,fd=32))
tcp     LISTEN   0        10                                  127.0.0.1:53                                           0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=29),("named",pid=34374,fd=28),("named",pid=34374,fd=27))
tcp     LISTEN   0        4096                            127.0.0.53%lo:53                                           0.0.0.0:*                                   users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=826,fd=13))                                      
tcp     LISTEN   0        10         [fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f]%enp0s25:53                                              [::]:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=44),("named",pid=34374,fd=43),("named",pid=34374,fd=42))
tcp     LISTEN   0        10                                      [::1]:53                                              [::]:*                                   users:(("named",pid=34374,fd=39),("named",pid=34374,fd=38),("named",pid=34374,fd=37))
```

[image]

Comment: `unable to listen on any configured interfaces` is pretty self-explanatory.  Something else is listening on port 53 on all the IPs on your system.

Comment: What could that be?

Comment: Could be anything.  Start by including the output of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':53'` into your question as an edit - that will help point at what else is listening on port 53 currently.

Comment: I get this 
`
sudo: unable to resolve host sturtz: Name or service not known
sudo: netstat: command not found
`

Comment: blah forget it's not shipped default anymore.  Try `sudo ss -tulpn | grep :53`?

Comment: Your output shows that `named` is already running.  Did you do `sudo systemctl stop named.service` and then `sudo systemctl start named.service`?

Comment: I get ```sudo: unable to resolve host sturtz: Name or service not known```

Comment: And yes I still get ```named.service is not active, cannot reload.```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108056/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-nathaniel-sturtz), as comments are not good for extended discussion and debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you had two problems:

(1) Stale `named` processes running which we killed with `sudo killall -9 named` and then started with `sudo systemctl start named.service`

(2) Configuration issues - the `forwarders` bit for DNS needs you to have actual IP addresses and not hostnames.  This said, you're running your site via CloudFlare, why do you need your own DNS for this?

Regardless both issues are fixed.  Refer to the [chat room referred to in comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108056/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-nathaniel-sturtz) for the detailed discussions on this.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: it stoped working for me, when I go to sturtz.ml I get This site can’t be reached

Comment: @NathanielSturtz you sure you don't have browser caching at play?  Cause it's still up here.

Comment: Yes, I am sure,

Comment: It was an issue with Cloudflare settings, the SSL was set to be off, why IDK

Comment: It went down for me on an external network.